# Sound Not Playing in iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I am making a small iOS game, and have finished everything, except the sound. I have checked the file formats, tried .wav and .aiff and none of them work. The related code is as follows:

`.h` file:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@public SystemSoundID mBeep;
NSString* path;
NSURL* url;
```

`.m` file:

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"hit" ofType:@"wav"];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)url, &mBeep);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mBeep); //Gets called, doesn't play
```

If I use one of the undocumented ids, like `1103` with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`, that sound plays fine.

I am quite sure my files are fine, as the same .wav file works perfectly on Android, VLC, iTunes etc.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely culprit is the encoding on the WAV. As indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566301/iphone-some-sound-files-not-playing/567812#567812), iOS only supports certain codecs, and the WAV you're trying to play probably uses an unsupported one.

Like that answer says, the easiest solution will be to use the command-line `afconvert` tool to (losslessly) convert your WAV to Apple's default CAF format and use that instead:

```
afconvert sound1.wav sound1.caf
```

Another possibility—and the actual problem the OP had—is that the file doesn't exist and/or `pathForResource` isn't successfully finding it, which would be indicated by `path` being `nil`.

Comment: I tried that. The command you gave didn't work, but with a bit of Googling the conversion took place with "afconvert -f caff -d aac -c 1 /Users/raghavsood/Desktop/iOS/Shared/Resources/hit.wav /Users/raghavsood/Desktop/iOS/Shared/Resources/hit.caf" Even after this the sound doesn't play. I also tried using the aiff format. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you check that you're successfully reading the file? Try doing something else with the file, like loading it into an NSData.

Comment: I used the following to read the data from the file:

    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];  
    if(fileData!=NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"File read");
    }

The log statement doesn't show up, so I guess the file isn't being read. I have tried altering the resource path. The file is stored in  /Shared/Resources. I have tried using relative paths, alternate paths and any other path I invented along the way. None of them worked. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't matter what physical folder the file is in, as long as it's actually **in** your Xcode directory. You probably want to look at [questions about pathForResource](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pathforresource). Chances are that method is failing, and `path` is `nil`.

Comment: You were right. The path was the problem, in addition to the format. For some reason, about halfway through the project xcode stopped packaging my "Sounds" subfolder. I added it back and it works perfectly.

Comment: Great! Glad it's working now. Feel free to award me that bounty ;)