# iOS - Add a custom alert sound

Tags: ios, audio, alert, uilocalnotification

I would like to add a custom alert sound to my iOS app. I have been trying to add it to my Xcode project but doesn't seem to work. I get the default alert sound instead of my custom alert sound.

Pardon my ignorance I know very little about sound file formats. I am confused if I am using the correct format.

Apple documentation states that I need to use one of the 4 formats (Linear PCM, MA4(IMA/ADPCM), µLaw, aLaw).

**What I have done**

- I have a file that has the extension .m4a (quick time)
- I also tried using the afconvert tool to convert it

  **afconvert test.m4a test.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v**
- The duration of the sound file is well below 30 seconds
- I have added the file on to my Xcode project by copying it and saving it in the location where my other source code files exist

When the notification is sent I get the default alert sound and not my custom alert sound.

I have tried the below mentioned 2 lines of code and doesn't seem to work, I get a default sound instead

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.soundName = @"test.caf";

//or .m4a file
localNotif.soundName = @"test.m4a";
```

**Questions:**

- Is .m4a a supported file format (is MA4 and .m4a the same ?)
- How can I create an audio file in one of the supported formats. Does Garage band have an option where I can save it in one of the supported formats ?
- What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tested the sound another way? I'd make sure that the file is actually being found. See what happened on this question, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451533/sound-not-playing-in-ios/9585954#9585954

Comment: I can't see exactly what your problem is, does the sound file play ok in iTunes for example? Can you play the sound directly in your program? However I can say that .m4a IS supported; I use them.

Comment: thanks a lot for both your replies. I made a blunder, while dragging and dropping the .m4a file, there is a dialogue window which opens and I hadn't checked the option to add it to the target. By default my app was unchecked and only my appNameTests was checked. I think that one corresponds to the test case.  Now it plays, thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The mistake I made**

- I made a blunder. When I dragged and dropped the .m4a file on to the Xcode project, a dialogue box opens asking me to select the target. By default the app wasn't selected, only the test case was selected.
- After selecting the the app's name, now it seems to be playing well.